# Rails 3 site running on passenger with php front page

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have my Rails 3 app running with Passenger.  I have a small site built in php that I want to act as the front page(s) to my site.  It contains a link that leads to the actual rails app.  The php stuff is located in a sub-directory of my public directory.

Right now setting the document root to /var/www/myapp/current/public will allow my site to work fine.  I tried setting the document root to /var/www/myapp/current/public/php_site, with PassengerEnabled set to off for the directory.  makes the php part work correctly as the default page when I go to my site, but then the rails app doe not work.  How can I get both the php part and the rails app working together?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do...

I have my Rails apps in /var/www-ruby/

My apache root is /var/www/

I also have some PHP stuff running in /var/www/

For any rails apps I need to serve through Passenger/Apache, I create a link to it from /var/www/ to /var/www-ruby/my-app-name/public/.

Example: current directory is /var/www/

ln -s /var/www-ruby/my-app-name/public/ my-app-name

Whenever someone goes to http://example.com/my-app-name, it will serve the contents of /var/www-ruby/my-app-name/public/

[edit]

Here's the relevant portions of my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


  RailsBaseURI /ticketqueue
    <Directory /var/www-ruby/ticketqueue>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

  RailsBaseURI /dashboard
    <Directory /var/www-ruby/dashboard>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

After you edit that file, you may need to disable and re-enable default by running `a2dissite default` and `a2ensite default` and reloading apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`